# Nothing happening when clicking HeadlessUI Component - Rendering button but not changing upon click

Tags: next.js, next.js13, headless-ui

I am testing out an example HeadlessUI Switch component, [see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUjI4.png)

I am using this inside of a server component (rendering is dependent upon login). As you can see the switch is rendering inside the parent component, [however when clicking on it nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s5B5.png). This is for all headlessUI and radixUI primitives.

I am using NextJS 14.1.0, React 18, HeadlessUI 0.0.0

Why might this be happening?

I have tried multiple different example components and absolutely nothing is happening when clicking.